# How to display TimeSpan on 30 minute

Tags: c#, timespan

I want to display TimeSpan on 30 minute loop through and only show it like this:

```
00:00

00:30

01:00

01:30
```

This is my code:

```html
<select class="form-control dropdown guestTitle">
 @{
   
  TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
  <option>00:00</option>
  for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
  {
   StartTime = StartTime.Add(new TimeSpan(00,30,0));
   <option>@StartTime</option>
  }                      
 }                                                                                           
</select>
```

It displays like:

```
 00:00

 00:30:00

 01:00:00

 01:30:00
```

My problem with this format is the seconds being shown. Also I want the time to be 24h format not 12h format.

Comment: use `.ToString("HH:mm")`

Comment: when i used it gives me error string wrong format

Comment: See this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings Also not that TimeSpan is a structure representing a time period NOT an actual time - as such the hours will always be 0-23.

Comment: @hashim: try @"hh\:mm" - link given in comment to answer below.

Comment: @PaulF @"hh\:mm" this format work , i need hours be 0-23 it now display 0-12

Comment: Your code only creates times for a 12 hour period (24 times, separated by half hour each) - if you increase your for loop to run 48 loops you should see hours going from 0-23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give it a format by `ToString`:

```
    <select class="form-control dropdown guestTitle">
    @{
       TimeSpan StartTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(0);
       <option>00:00</option>
       for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++)
           {
               StartTime = StartTime.Add(new TimeSpan(00,30,0));
               <option>@StartTime.ToString("hh\\:mm")</option>
           }                      
      }                                                                                           
  </select>
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format. this error when i put  `.ToString("HH:mm")`

Comment: I think you will find the correct format string for a TimeSpan is @"hh\:mm" - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani  thanks , it is work also your format , i need also hours be 0-23 it now display 0-12

Comment: @hashim its 24 hour format. note that your for loop repeats 24 times each half an hour that would make 12 hours. if you want 24 hours, you should make your loop repeat 48 times (i<48)